# Problem reading the Content Sequence tag of DICOM file using DCMTK

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

Using DCMTK, I am trying to get the entire node of Content Sequence of .dcm SR files to extract measurements related to obstetrical scans. I use C-Find query. I am able to get the entire Content Sequence with Toshiba ultrasound machine but not with other brands. I don't think that  this is a brand issue but the way I have set up the C-Find process. I am very new to this and am struggling to resolve the issue. I have included 2 log files below: one for the working case that successfully gets the entire node of Content Sequence tag, and another log for the non-working case that stops the process with an error "DIMSE Status: 0xc000: Error: Failed - Unable to process error". I appreciate any help or your insightful advice.

This the log for the non-working query

```
D: Request Parameters:
D: ====================== BEGIN A-ASSOCIATE-RQ =====================
D: Our Implementation Class UID:      1.2.276.0.7230010.3.0.3.6.5
D: Our Implementation Version Name:   OFFIS_DCMTK_365
D: Their Implementation Class UID:    
D: Their Implementation Version Name: 
D: Application Context Name:    1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1
D: Calling Application Name:    KATIBA
D: Called Application Name:     ORTHANC
D: Responding Application Name: ORTHANC
D: Our Max PDU Receive Size:    16384
D: Their Max PDU Receive Size:  0
D: Presentation Contexts:
D:   Context ID:        1 (Proposed)
D:     Abstract Syntax: =FINDStudyRootQueryRetrieveInformationModel
D:     Proposed SCP/SCU Role: Default
D:     Proposed Transfer Syntax(es):
D:       =LittleEndianExplicit
D:       =BigEndianExplicit
D:       =LittleEndianImplicit
D: Requested Extended Negotiation: none
D: Accepted Extended Negotiation:  none
D: Requested User Identity Negotiation: none
D: User Identity Negotiation Response:  none
D: ======================= END A-ASSOCIATE-RQ ======================
I: Requesting Association
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 1 Event: 0
T: DUL  Event:  A-ASSOCIATE request (local user)
T: DUL  Action: AE 1 Transport Connect
D: setting network send timeout to 60 seconds
D: setting network receive timeout to 60 seconds
T: checking whether environment variable TCP_BUFFER_LENGTH is set
T:   environment variable TCP_BUFFER_LENGTH not set, using the system defaults
T: checking whether environment variable TCP_NODELAY is set
T:   environment variable TCP_NODELAY not set, using the default value (0)
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 4 Event: 1
T: DUL  Event:  Transport conn confirmation (local)
T: DUL  Action: AE 2 Send Associate RQ PDU
D: Constructing Associate RQ PDU
T: setting timeout for first PDU to be read to 30 seconds
T: Read PDU HEAD TCP: 02 00 00 00 00 ba
T: Read PDU HEAD TCP: type: 02, length: 186 (ba)
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 5 Event: 2
T: DUL  Event:  A-ASSOCIATE-AC PDU (on transport)
T: DUL  Action: AE 3 Associate Confirmation Accept
D: PDU Type: Associate Accept, PDU Length: 186 + 6 bytes PDU header
D:   02  00  00  00  00  ba  00  01  00  00  4f  52  54  48  41  4e
D:   43  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  4b  41  54  49  42  41
D:   20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  00  00  00  00  00  00
D:   00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
D:   00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  10  00  00  15  31  2e
D:   32  2e  38  34  30  2e  31  30  30  30  38  2e  33  2e  31  2e
D:   31  2e  31  21  00  00  1b  01  00  00  00  40  00  00  13  31
D:   2e  32  2e  38  34  30  2e  31  30  30  30  38  2e  31  2e  32
D:   2e  31  50  00  00  3a  51  00  00  04  00  00  40  00  52  00
D:   00  1b  31  2e  32  2e  32  37  36  2e  30  2e  37  32  33  30
D:   30  31  30  2e  33  2e  30  2e  33  2e  36  2e  34  55  00  00
D:   0f  4f  46  46  49  53  5f  44  43  4d  54  4b  5f  33  36  34
D: 
D: Parsing an A-ASSOCIATE PDU
T: PDU type: 2 (A-ASSOCIATE AC), PDU Length: 186
T: DICOM Protocol: 1
T: Called AP Title:  ORTHANC
T: Calling AP Title: KATIBA
T: Parsing remaining 118 bytes of A-ASSOCIATE PDU
T: Next item type: 10
T: Subitem parse: Type 10, Length 0021, Content: 1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1
T: Successfully parsed Application Context
T: Parsing remaining 93 bytes of A-ASSOCIATE PDU
T: Next item type: 21
T: Parsing Presentation Context: (21), Length: 27
T: Presentation Context ID: 01
T: Parsing remaining 23 bytes of Presentation Context
T: Next item type: 40
T: Subitem parse: Type 40, Length 0019, Content: 1.2.840.10008.1.2.1
T: Successfully parsed Transfer Syntax
T: Successfully parsed Presentation Context
T: Parsing remaining 62 bytes of A-ASSOCIATE PDU
T: Next item type: 50
T: Parsing user info field (50), Length: 58
T: Parsing remaining 58 bytes of User Information
T: Next item type: 51
T: Maximum PDU Length: 16384
T: Successfully parsed Maximum PDU Length
T: Parsing remaining 50 bytes of User Information
T: Next item type: 52
T: Subitem parse: Type 52, Length 0027, Content: 1.2.276.0.7230010.3.0.3.6.4
T: Parsing remaining 19 bytes of User Information
T: Next item type: 55
T: Subitem parse: Type 55, Length 0015, Content: OFFIS_DCMTK_364
T: Successfully parsed User Information
D: Association Parameters Negotiated:
D: ====================== BEGIN A-ASSOCIATE-AC =====================
D: Our Implementation Class UID:      1.2.276.0.7230010.3.0.3.6.5
D: Our Implementation Version Name:   OFFIS_DCMTK_365
D: Their Implementation Class UID:    1.2.276.0.7230010.3.0.3.6.4
D: Their Implementation Version Name: OFFIS_DCMTK_364
D: Application Context Name:    1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1
D: Calling Application Name:    KATIBA
D: Called Application Name:     ORTHANC
D: Responding Application Name: ORTHANC
D: Our Max PDU Receive Size:    16384
D: Their Max PDU Receive Size:  16384
D: Presentation Contexts:
D:   Context ID:        1 (Accepted)
D:     Abstract Syntax: =FINDStudyRootQueryRetrieveInformationModel
D:     Proposed SCP/SCU Role: Default
D:     Accepted SCP/SCU Role: Default
D:     Accepted Transfer Syntax: =LittleEndianExplicit
D: Requested Extended Negotiation: none
D: Accepted Extended Negotiation:  none
D: Requested User Identity Negotiation: none
D: User Identity Negotiation Response:  none
D: ======================= END A-ASSOCIATE-AC ======================
I: Association Accepted (Max Send PDV: 16372)

I: Sending Find Request
D: ===================== OUTGOING DIMSE MESSAGE ====================
D: Message Type                  : C-FIND RQ
D: Presentation Context ID       : 1
D: Message ID                    : 1
D: Affected SOP Class UID        : FINDStudyRootQueryRetrieveInformationModel
D: Data Set                      : present
D: Priority                      : medium
D: ======================= END DIMSE MESSAGE =======================
I: Request Identifiers:
I: 
I: # Dicom-Data-Set
I: # Used TransferSyntax: Little Endian Explicit
I: (0008,0016) UI (no value available)                     #   0, 0 SOPClassUID
I: (0008,0018) UI (no value available)                     #   0, 0 SOPInstanceUID
I: (0008,0020) DA [20210218-]                              #  10, 1 StudyDate
I: (0008,0021) DA [20210218-]                              #  10, 1 SeriesDate
I: (0008,0030) TM [0000-2359]                              #  10, 1 StudyTime
I: (0008,0031) TM [0000-2359]                              #  10, 1 SeriesTime
I: (0008,0050) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 AccessionNumber
I: (0008,0052) CS [SERIES]                                 #   6, 1 QueryRetrieveLevel
I: (0008,0061) CS [SR]                                     #   2, 1 ModalitiesInStudy
I: (0008,0070) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 Manufacturer
I: (0008,0080) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 InstitutionName
I: (0008,0090) PN (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ReferringPhysicianName
I: (0008,1030) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 StudyDescription
I: (0008,103e) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 SeriesDescription
I: (0008,1040) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 InstitutionalDepartmentName
I: (0008,1048) PN (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PhysiciansOfRecord
I: (0010,0010) PN (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientName
I: (0010,0020) LO [200167394]                              #  10, 1 PatientID
I: (0010,0030) DA (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientBirthDate
I: (0010,0040) CS (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientSex
I: (0010,1010) AS (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientAge
I: (0010,21b0) LT (no value available)                     #   0, 0 AdditionalPatientHistory
I: (0020,000d) UI (no value available)                     #   0, 0 StudyInstanceUID
I: (0020,0010) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 StudyID
I: (0032,1032) PN (no value available)                     #   0, 0 RequestingPhysician
I: (0040,a730) SQ (Sequence with explicit length #=0)      #   0, 1 ContentSequence
I: (fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem for re-encod.) #   0, 0 SequenceDelimitationItem
I: 
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0000) VR="UL" inserted at beginning
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0100) VR="US" inserted
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0110) VR="US" inserted
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0800) VR="US" inserted

T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0002) VR="UI" inserted
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0700) VR="US" inserted
T: DIMSE Command to be sent on Presentation Context ID: 1
T: DIMSE Command to send:
T: 
T: # Dicom-Data-Set
T: # Used TransferSyntax: Little Endian Explicit
T: (0000,0000) UL 0                                        #   4, 1 CommandGroupLength
T: (0000,0002) UI =FINDStudyRootQueryRetrieveInformationModel #  28, 1 AffectedSOPClassUID
T: (0000,0100) US 32                                       #   2, 1 CommandField
T: (0000,0110) US 1                                        #   2, 1 MessageID
T: (0000,0700) US 0                                        #   2, 1 Priority
T: (0000,0800) US 1                                        #   2, 1 CommandDataSetType
T: 
T: DIMSE sendDcmDataset: sending 88 bytes
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 6 Event: 8
T: DUL  Event:  P-DATA request primitive
T: DUL  Action: DT 1 Send P DATA PDU
T: DIMSE sendDcmDataset: sending 270 bytes
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 6 Event: 8
T: DUL  Event:  P-DATA request primitive
T: DUL  Action: DT 1 Send P DATA PDU
T: DIMSE receiveCommand
T: Read PDU HEAD TCP: 04 00 00 00 00 5e
T: Read PDU HEAD TCP: type: 04, length: 94 (5e)
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 6 Event: 9
T: DUL  Event:  P-DATA-TF PDU (on transport)
T: DUL  Action: DT 2 Indicate P DATA PDU Received
D: DcmDataset::read() TransferSyntax="Little Endian Implicit"
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0000) VR="UL" inserted at beginning
T: DcmItem::readSubItem() returns error = Normal
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0002) VR="UI" inserted
T: DcmItem::readSubItem() returns error = Normal
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0100) VR="US" inserted
T: DcmItem::readSubItem() returns error = Normal
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0120) VR="US" inserted
T: DcmItem::readSubItem() returns error = Normal
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0800) VR="US" inserted
T: DcmItem::readSubItem() returns error = Normal
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0900) VR="US" inserted
T: DcmItem::readSubItem() returns error = Normal
T: DcmItem::read() returns error = Normal
T: DcmDataset::read() returns error = Normal
T: DIMSE receiveCommand: 1 PDVs (88 bytes), PresID=1
T: DIMSE Command Received:
T: 
T: # Dicom-Data-Set
T: # Used TransferSyntax: Little Endian Implicit
T: (0000,0002) UI =FINDStudyRootQueryRetrieveInformationModel #  28, 1 AffectedSOPClassUID
T: (0000,0100) US 32800                                    #   2, 1 CommandField
T: (0000,0120) US 1                                        #   2, 1 MessageIDBeingRespondedTo
T: (0000,0800) US 257                                      #   2, 1 CommandDataSetType
T: (0000,0900) US 49152                                    #   2, 1 Status
T: 
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0100) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0100) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0120) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0800) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0900) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0002) found
I: Received Final Find Response
D: ===================== INCOMING DIMSE MESSAGE ====================
D: Message Type                  : C-FIND RSP
D: Message ID Being Responded To : 1
D: Affected SOP Class UID        : FINDStudyRootQueryRetrieveInformationModel
D: Data Set                      : none
D: DIMSE Status                  : 0xc000: Error: Failed - Unable to process
D: ======================= END DIMSE MESSAGE =======================
I: Releasing Association
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 6 Event: 10
T: DUL  Event:  A-RELEASE request primitive
T: DUL  Action: AR 1 Send Release RQ
T: Read PDU HEAD TCP: 06 00 00 00 00 04
T: Read PDU HEAD TCP: type: 06, length: 4 (04)
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 7 Event: 12
T: DUL  Event:  A-RELEASE-RP PDU (on transport)
T: DUL  Action: AR 3 Confirm Release
```

And this is the log for the working query:

```
D: Request Parameters:
D: ====================== BEGIN A-ASSOCIATE-RQ =====================
D: Our Implementation Class UID:      1.2.276.0.7230010.3.0.3.6.5
D: Our Implementation Version Name:   OFFIS_DCMTK_365
D: Their Implementation Class UID:    
D: Their Implementation Version Name: 
D: Application Context Name:    1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1
D: Calling Application Name:    KATIBA
D: Called Application Name:     ORTHANC
D: Responding Application Name: ORTHANC
D: Our Max PDU Receive Size:    16384
D: Their Max PDU Receive Size:  0
D: Presentation Contexts:
D:   Context ID:        1 (Proposed)
D:     Abstract Syntax: =FINDStudyRootQueryRetrieveInformationModel
D:     Proposed SCP/SCU Role: Default
D:     Proposed Transfer Syntax(es):
D:       =LittleEndianExplicit
D:       =BigEndianExplicit
D:       =LittleEndianImplicit
D: Requested Extended Negotiation: none
D: Accepted Extended Negotiation:  none
D: Requested User Identity Negotiation: none
D: User Identity Negotiation Response:  none
D: ======================= END A-ASSOCIATE-RQ ======================
I: Requesting Association
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 1 Event: 0
T: DUL  Event:  A-ASSOCIATE request (local user)
T: DUL  Action: AE 1 Transport Connect
D: setting network send timeout to 60 seconds
D: setting network receive timeout to 60 seconds
T: checking whether environment variable TCP_BUFFER_LENGTH is set
T:   environment variable TCP_BUFFER_LENGTH not set, using the system defaults
T: checking whether environment variable TCP_NODELAY is set
T:   environment variable TCP_NODELAY not set, using the default value (0)
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 4 Event: 1
T: DUL  Event:  Transport conn confirmation (local)
T: DUL  Action: AE 2 Send Associate RQ PDU
D: Constructing Associate RQ PDU
T: setting timeout for first PDU to be read to 30 seconds
T: Read PDU HEAD TCP: 02 00 00 00 00 ba
T: Read PDU HEAD TCP: type: 02, length: 186 (ba)
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 5 Event: 2
T: DUL  Event:  A-ASSOCIATE-AC PDU (on transport)
T: DUL  Action: AE 3 Associate Confirmation Accept
D: PDU Type: Associate Accept, PDU Length: 186 + 6 bytes PDU header
D:   02  00  00  00  00  ba  00  01  00  00  4f  52  54  48  41  4e
D:   43  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  4b  41  54  49  42  41
D:   20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  00  00  00  00  00  00
D:   00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
D:   00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  10  00  00  15  31  2e
D:   32  2e  38  34  30  2e  31  30  30  30  38  2e  33  2e  31  2e
D:   31  2e  31  21  00  00  1b  01  00  00  00  40  00  00  13  31
D:   2e  32  2e  38  34  30  2e  31  30  30  30  38  2e  31  2e  32
D:   2e  31  50  00  00  3a  51  00  00  04  00  00  40  00  52  00
D:   00  1b  31  2e  32  2e  32  37  36  2e  30  2e  37  32  33  30
D:   30  31  30  2e  33  2e  30  2e  33  2e  36  2e  34  55  00  00
D:   0f  4f  46  46  49  53  5f  44  43  4d  54  4b  5f  33  36  34
D: 
D: Parsing an A-ASSOCIATE PDU
T: PDU type: 2 (A-ASSOCIATE AC), PDU Length: 186
T: DICOM Protocol: 1
T: Called AP Title:  ORTHANC
T: Calling AP Title: KATIBA
T: Parsing remaining 118 bytes of A-ASSOCIATE PDU
T: Next item type: 10
T: Subitem parse: Type 10, Length 0021, Content: 1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1
T: Successfully parsed Application Context
T: Parsing remaining 93 bytes of A-ASSOCIATE PDU
T: Next item type: 21
T: Parsing Presentation Context: (21), Length: 27
T: Presentation Context ID: 01
T: Parsing remaining 23 bytes of Presentation Context
T: Next item type: 40
T: Subitem parse: Type 40, Length 0019, Content: 1.2.840.10008.1.2.1
T: Successfully parsed Transfer Syntax
T: Successfully parsed Presentation Context
T: Parsing remaining 62 bytes of A-ASSOCIATE PDU
T: Next item type: 50
T: Parsing user info field (50), Length: 58
T: Parsing remaining 58 bytes of User Information
T: Next item type: 51
T: Maximum PDU Length: 16384
T: Successfully parsed Maximum PDU Length
T: Parsing remaining 50 bytes of User Information
T: Next item type: 52
T: Subitem parse: Type 52, Length 0027, Content: 1.2.276.0.7230010.3.0.3.6.4
T: Parsing remaining 19 bytes of User Information
T: Next item type: 55
T: Subitem parse: Type 55, Length 0015, Content: OFFIS_DCMTK_364
T: Successfully parsed User Information
D: Association Parameters Negotiated:
D: ====================== BEGIN A-ASSOCIATE-AC =====================
D: Our Implementation Class UID:      1.2.276.0.7230010.3.0.3.6.5
D: Our Implementation Version Name:   OFFIS_DCMTK_365
D: Their Implementation Class UID:    1.2.276.0.7230010.3.0.3.6.4
D: Their Implementation Version Name: OFFIS_DCMTK_364
D: Application Context Name:    1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1
D: Calling Application Name:    KATIBA
D: Called Application Name:     ORTHANC
D: Responding Application Name: ORTHANC
D: Our Max PDU Receive Size:    16384
D: Their Max PDU Receive Size:  16384
D: Presentation Contexts:
D:   Context ID:        1 (Accepted)
D:     Abstract Syntax: =FINDStudyRootQueryRetrieveInformationModel
D:     Proposed SCP/SCU Role: Default
D:     Accepted SCP/SCU Role: Default
D:     Accepted Transfer Syntax: =LittleEndianExplicit
D: Requested Extended Negotiation: none
D: Accepted Extended Negotiation:  none
D: Requested User Identity Negotiation: none
D: User Identity Negotiation Response:  none
D: ======================= END A-ASSOCIATE-AC ======================
I: Association Accepted (Max Send PDV: 16372)

I: Sending Find Request
D: ===================== OUTGOING DIMSE MESSAGE ====================
D: Message Type                  : C-FIND RQ
D: Presentation Context ID       : 1
D: Message ID                    : 1
D: Affected SOP Class UID        : FINDStudyRootQueryRetrieveInformationModel
D: Data Set                      : present
D: Priority                      : medium
D: ======================= END DIMSE MESSAGE =======================
I: Request Identifiers:
I: 
I: # Dicom-Data-Set
I: # Used TransferSyntax: Little Endian Explicit
I: (0008,0016) UI (no value available)                     #   0, 0 SOPClassUID
I: (0008,0018) UI (no value available)                     #   0, 0 SOPInstanceUID
I: (0008,0020) DA [20210218-]                              #  10, 1 StudyDate
I: (0008,0021) DA [20210218-]                              #  10, 1 SeriesDate
I: (0008,0030) TM [0000-2359]                              #  10, 1 StudyTime
I: (0008,0031) TM [0000-2359]                              #  10, 1 SeriesTime
I: (0008,0050) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 AccessionNumber
I: (0008,0052) CS [SERIES]                                 #   6, 1 QueryRetrieveLevel
I: (0008,0061) CS [SR]                                     #   2, 1 ModalitiesInStudy
I: (0008,0070) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 Manufacturer
I: (0008,0080) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 InstitutionName
I: (0008,0090) PN (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ReferringPhysicianName
I: (0008,1030) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 StudyDescription
I: (0008,103e) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 SeriesDescription
I: (0008,1040) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 InstitutionalDepartmentName
I: (0008,1048) PN (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PhysiciansOfRecord
I: (0010,0010) PN (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientName
I: (0010,0020) LO [01TEST12]                               #   8, 1 PatientID
I: (0010,0030) DA (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientBirthDate
I: (0010,0040) CS (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientSex
I: (0010,1010) AS (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientAge
I: (0010,21b0) LT (no value available)                     #   0, 0 AdditionalPatientHistory
I: (0020,000d) UI (no value available)                     #   0, 0 StudyInstanceUID
I: (0020,0010) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 StudyID
I: (0032,1032) PN (no value available)                     #   0, 0 RequestingPhysician
I: (0040,a730) SQ (Sequence with explicit length #=0)      #   0, 1 ContentSequence
I: (fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem for re-encod.) #   0, 0 SequenceDelimitationItem
I: 
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0000) VR="UL" inserted at beginning
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0100) VR="US" inserted
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0110) VR="US" inserted
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0800) VR="US" inserted
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0002) VR="UI" inserted
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0700) VR="US" inserted
T: DIMSE Command to be sent on Presentation Context ID: 1
T: DIMSE Command to send:
T: 
T: # Dicom-Data-Set
T: # Used TransferSyntax: Little Endian Explicit
T: (0000,0000) UL 0                                        #   4, 1 CommandGroupLength
T: (0000,0002) UI =FINDStudyRootQueryRetrieveInformationModel #  28, 1 AffectedSOPClassUID
T: (0000,0100) US 32                                       #   2, 1 CommandField
T: (0000,0110) US 1                                        #   2, 1 MessageID
T: (0000,0700) US 0                                        #   2, 1 Priority
T: (0000,0800) US 1                                        #   2, 1 CommandDataSetType
T: 
T: DIMSE sendDcmDataset: sending 88 bytes
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 6 Event: 8
T: DUL  Event:  P-DATA request primitive
T: DUL  Action: DT 1 Send P DATA PDU
T: DIMSE sendDcmDataset: sending 268 bytes
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 6 Event: 8
T: DUL  Event:  P-DATA request primitive
T: DUL  Action: DT 1 Send P DATA PDU
T: DIMSE receiveCommand
T: Read PDU HEAD TCP: 04 00 00 00 00 5e
T: Read PDU HEAD TCP: type: 04, length: 94 (5e)
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 6 Event: 9
T: DUL  Event:  P-DATA-TF PDU (on transport)
T: DUL  Action: DT 2 Indicate P DATA PDU Received
D: DcmDataset::read() TransferSyntax="Little Endian Implicit"
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0000) VR="UL" inserted at beginning
T: DcmItem::readSubItem() returns error = Normal
T: DcmDataset::read() returns error = Normal

T: DIMSE receiveCommand: 1 PDVs (88 bytes), PresID=1
T: DIMSE Command Received:
T: 
T: # Dicom-Data-Set
T: # Used TransferSyntax: Little Endian Implicit
T: (0000,0002) UI =FINDStudyRootQueryRetrieveInformationModel #  28, 1 AffectedSOPClassUID
T: (0000,0100) US 32800                                    #   2, 1 CommandField
T: (0000,0120) US 1                                        #   2, 1 MessageIDBeingRespondedTo
T: (0000,0800) US 1                                        #   2, 1 CommandDataSetType
T: (0000,0900) US 65280                                    #   2, 1 Status
T: 
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0100) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0100) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0120) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0800) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0900) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0002) found
T: Read PDU HEAD TCP: 04 00 00 00 3f f8
T: Read PDU HEAD TCP: type: 04, length: 16376 (3ff8)
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 6 Event: 9
T: DUL  Event:  P-DATA-TF PDU (on transport)
T: DUL  Action: DT 2 Indicate P DATA PDU Received
D: DcmDataset::read() TransferSyntax="Little Endian Explicit"

T: DcmSequenceOfItems::read() returns error = Normal
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0040,a043) VR="SQ" inserted
T: DcmItem::readSubItem() returns error = Normal
T: DIMSE receiveDataSetInMemory: 11642 bytes read (last: YES)
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0008,0018) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0008,0016) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0040,a730) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0040,a010) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0040,a040) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0040,a043) found
//more truncated repetitive log
T: DIMSE receiveCommand
T: Read PDU HEAD TCP: 04 00 00 00 00 5e
T: Read PDU HEAD TCP: type: 04, length: 94 (5e)
T: DUL  FSM Table: State: 6 Event: 9
T: DUL  Event:  P-DATA-TF PDU (on transport)
T: DUL  Action: DT 2 Indicate P DATA PDU Received
D: DcmDataset::read() TransferSyntax="Little Endian Implicit"
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0000) VR="UL" inserted at beginning
T: DcmItem::readSubItem() returns error = Normal
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0002) VR="UI" inserted
T: DcmItem::readSubItem() returns error = Normal
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0100) VR="US" inserted
T: DcmItem::readSubItem() returns error = Normal
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0120) VR="US" inserted
T: DcmItem::readSubItem() returns error = Normal
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0800) VR="US" inserted
T: DcmItem::readSubItem() returns error = Normal
T: DcmItem::insert() Element (0000,0900) VR="US" inserted
T: DcmItem::readSubItem() returns error = Normal
T: DcmItem::read() returns error = Normal
T: DcmDataset::read() returns error = Normal
T: DIMSE receiveCommand: 1 PDVs (88 bytes), PresID=1
T: DIMSE Command Received:
T: 
T: # Dicom-Data-Set
T: # Used TransferSyntax: Little Endian Implicit
T: (0000,0002) UI =FINDStudyRootQueryRetrieveInformationModel #  28, 1 AffectedSOPClassUID
T: (0000,0100) US 32800                                    #   2, 1 CommandField
T: (0000,0120) US 1                                        #   2, 1 MessageIDBeingRespondedTo
T: (0000,0800) US 257                                      #   2, 1 CommandDataSetType
T: (0000,0900) US 0                                        #   2, 1 Status
T: 
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0100) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0100) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0120) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0800) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0900) found
T: DcmItem::searchSubFromHere() Element (0000,0002) found
I: Received Final Find Response
D: ===================== INCOMING DIMSE MESSAGE ====================
D: Message Type                  : C-FIND RSP
D: Message ID Being Responded To : 1
D: Affected SOP Class UID        : FINDStudyRootQueryRetrieveInformationModel
D: Data Set                      : none
D: DIMSE Status                  : 0x0000: Success
D: ======================= END DIMSE MESSAGE =======================
I: Releasing Association
```

Comment: May be helpful: [Q/R workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44322106/5779732) and [more details with specification references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55488689/5779732).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requests only differ in that your non-working query queries for a different patient ID.

An obvious mistake in both queries is that for a SERIES-level request in STUDY-ROOT, you must not include a value for the Patient ID, but for the Study Instance UID. This is wrong in terms of DICOM, but Orthanc seems to be capable of handling it in general. This is however the only hint that I can obtain from your logs, so I would give it a try.

Please note, that the Content Sequence is not a mandatory Return Key for the C-FIND, so you can never rely on the SCP supporting it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It has to be SERIES-level in order to have access to SR file which contains the Content Sequence. The Sr file is one of the series of the patient ultrasound study. The patientID is just for the purpose of creating the log for this question to compare the logs for the working case and non-working case. Your comments about Content Sequence is not a mandatory Return key is very valuable information. Thank you!

Comment: Nothing speaks against using a SERIES-Level query, but prior to that, it is imperative to find the Study Instance UID by a STUDY-Level query. This is needed to meet the conformance requirements four your Series-level request.

Comment: I modified the query per your advice and now it does two queries, first at study level to get all studies and then a second query with the study instance UID to get the series with SR modality. Thank you!

Comment: You mentioned that Content Sequence is not a mandatory Return Key for C-FIND, so what is the best practice to get it? Should I use C-MOVE instead of C-FIND and save the SR file in our application first and then get the Content Sequence node?

Comment: Furthermore, the attribute Content Sequence is not associated with the SERIES level but with the IMAGE level (Composite Object Instance Level). Using Content Sequence as a Query Key also makes no sense to me. You should rather download the respective SR document and extract the Content Sequence from it.

Comment: Thanks @J.Riesmeier and @kritzel_sw, I changed it to C-MOVE and at "IMAGE" level and save the SR file to client's device directory and then I extract the elements of ContentSequence. This is working fine with my local Orthanc but at our testing site, the C-MOVE is sent and received C-MOVE Response is "SUCCESS" but the SR file is not copied to the destination directory without BEGIN A-ASSOCIATE-RQ. The end part of the log: `I: END A-
I: Association Accepted (Max Send PDV: 16372)
I: Sending C-MOVE Request (MsgID 1)
I: Received C-MOVE Response (Success)
I: Aborting Association`

Comment: @DORI: It smells like a problem with the contents of the SR that you are transferring. I do not think that this can be solved by a conversation in the comments. I propose that you open a new question and post logs of the movescu at debug level

Comment: @kritzel_sw: Yes I agree. I will open a new question and include the log. Thank you!